# Save Level screenshot and upload to Google+ in LIBGDX

Tags: android-activity, libgdx, google-play-services, scene2d

When in FINISHED-LEVEL mode, I'm print-screening my game screen in a PNG and save that to a file (**saveScreenshotNamePath**). I then want to upload that level picture to Google+ using **shareGoogleImage**. I tested the share function with text only and it works but I'm having problems with the image sharing part.

The print screen is nowhere to be seen in the Google upload dialog that appears, **I only see the title text**; apparently the image is not attached. What could be the issue here?

Here's the code:

This saves the print-screen to a file:

```
public static String saveScreenshotNamePath(String name){
    try{
        FileHandle fh;
        do{
            fh = new FileHandle(name + ".png");
        }while (fh.exists());
        Pixmap pixmap = getScreenshot(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);
        PixmapIO.writePNG(fh, pixmap);
        pixmap.dispose();
        return fh.file().getAbsolutePath();
    }catch (Exception e){
        return "";
    }        
}
```

This starts the Intent:

```
@Override
public void shareGoogleImage(int no_level, String path) {
    try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    Intent share = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
        .setText("See my latest Game Level " + Integer.toString(no_level) + " score")
        .setType("image/png")
        .setStream(Uri.parse(path)).getIntent();
    startActivityForResult(share, 0);
}
```

I also tried the **MediaStore** variant but I have the same result:

```
@Override
public void shareGoogleImage(int no_level, String path) {
    File tmpFile = new File(path);
    String photoUri = "";
    try {
        photoUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), tmpFile.getAbsolutePath(), null, null); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }

    try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    Intent share = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
        .setText("See my latest Game Level " + Integer.toString(no_level) + " score")
        .setType("image/png")
        .setStream(Uri.parse(photoUri))
        .getIntent();
    startActivityForResult(share, 0);
}
```

This is the in-game (core files) trigger (Scene2D ImageButton press) in my game screen for the **shareGoogleImage** function located inside AndroidLauncher.java (Activity file):

```
ShareGoogleButton.addListener( new ClickListener() {
@Override
public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){
    if(!share_pressed){ 
        share_pressed = true;
        ShareGoogleButton.clearActions();
        ShareGoogleButton.addAction(sequence(moveBy(0f, 12f, 0.1f), moveBy(0f, -12f, 0.2f), run(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){  
                String pathto_screencap = ScreenshotFactory.saveScreenshotNamePath("google_share_image");
                game.google_facebook_services.shareGoogleImage(level_no, pathto_screencap);
                share_pressed = false;
            }
        })));                   
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two problems here: an infinite loop and an absolute file path. Since you wrapped it in a catch-all `catch` block with no useful logging, you aren't getting any log messages to help you debug it.

This will be an infinite loop after the first time the method is called because the file will exist (assuming it is successfully written). Not sure why you have this.

```
do{
    fh = new FileHandle(name + ".png");
}while (fh.exists());
```

Anyway, you need to save it to an external directory (not an absolute one) if you want it to be shared with other apps like G+, so replace it with this:

```
fh = Gdx.files.external(name + ".png");
```

You also need the write-external-storage permission in your manifest:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you, never though of that do...while . I just pasted the code from here : https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Take-a-Screenshot . THANK YOU!